# SELECT * FROM table_name give me only one column as result

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python 2.7 and sqlite3 as DB, I am trying to call from this table :

[image]

using this code :

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM reports")
for row in c.fetchall():
    print row
```

and the result is :

```
0
1204
```

which is only the `id` column, despite I am using `fetchall()` and used `SELECT  *`

### update

After removing `conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]` the result is :

```
(0, u'\u062f\u062e\u0648\u0644', u'\u0643\u0631\u0633\u0649', 8, u'\u0623\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0648\u062c\u062f\u0649', u'2018-03-28')
(1204, u'\u062e\u0631\u0648\u062c', u'\u0643\u0631\u0633\u0649', 3, u'\u0623\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0648\u062c\u062f\u0649', u'2018-03-28')
```

then tried to add utf-encoding to the connection but still the same result, i used `c.execute('PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";')`

Comment: What happens if you remove line `conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]`?

Comment: Added the result as an update to the question

Comment: Is that output different than the desired output in any way?

Comment: yes that output should be a normal string or list as it is shown in the table's image, but the weird that it tupil and appear as numbers ( i think its encoding problem but I can't solve it )

Comment: you’ll need to add your desired encoding as well to the connection

Comment: tried to add encoding to the connection but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, as a tuple item cannot accept-encoding, I applied utf-8 encoding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the whole document and extracted names one by one as str from the list and the result is now fixed :

here is the updated code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 

conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM reports")
for row in c.fetchall():
    for names in row:
        print names
```

Answer (score 0):

- In the mentioned issue.

  conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]

You are explicitly calling first row[0] you are getting only one column.
Either try by row[0],row[1],row[2] depending on number of colums.